# iOS Apps Development Tools

Tags: ios

I am the beginner for iOS app development. I need few informations regarding development tools and versions I should use to develop the app which should work in IOS 4 and above and should run in iPhone and iPad.
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download Xcode from the Mac App store it should have the latest SDK and should be the latest version of Xcode.  Is this what you looking for?
The latest vesion of Xcode will let you develop in all released version.

Comment: Thanks lot. Which version of mac book OS version I need to develop apps for 4 and above?

Comment: This should get you started, alot of this material can be found if you do a bit of research on it.  https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Thanks for the material. Actually I dont have mac book, so I am planning to rent a mac book.so what would be the mac version I should target for to develop the app for 4 and above and also to run the latest xcode. May be this is bthe asic question, please excuse.

Comment: Xcode 4.5.2 requires at least Mac OS X 10.7.4 to be installed.  This will allow you to target development for iOS 4 and above if you wish.

Comment: It needs to be made clear that Xcode 4.5 supports iOS 4.3 and later, not just any versions of iOS 4.x.

Comment: very useful. thanks maddy

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a MAC with OSX installed.

Then, you have to download the last version of [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). After that open XCode and press create a new project.

So, a couple of notes to develop for iOS4:

- If you choose a template that can use storyboards (like master-detail application) then deselect the option "Use Storyboards". Storyboards are not supported in iOS4.
- You can use Automate Reference Counting
- Select the option Universal to develop for both iPhone and iPad

You should have something like this:

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3ruWy4dLJ4
Refer to this tutorial